# Not able to connect Play 1.2.5 framework to oracle10gR3 however from a simple Java class it is working fine

Tags: playframework

I am trying to connect my Application in Play Framework 1.2.5 to oracle 10g, but I am getting following error

Database error 
A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

configuration in application.conf are -

```
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.123.99:1521/HERMES"
db.user="hermes"
db.pass="hermes"
```

When I tried connecting it through a java class it work fine. My Java class is -

```
public class OraConnect {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.123.99:1521:HERMES", "hermes",
                    "hermes");
            Statement st=connection.createStatement();
            String query="select * from DBUser";
            ResultSet Set=st.executeQuery(query);

            while(Set.next()){
                System.out.println(Set.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }
      }
}
```

I read several forums. All are saying to use ojdbc14.jar in lib folder. And the also url String is correct. I used both older and latest version(1.5 MB), but not able to resolve my problem. I am able to connect it from SQLDeveloper also but not from play.
Please Help me with this.

Here is a screenshot for the error-

![
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

ORA-12514][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Vts.jpg)

Comment: That means it found the driver alright but that the driver failed to connect to the db server because of the error ORA-12514 which seems to be that the oracle service name is incorrect. Could it be that you put a slash between 1521 and HERMES in your config?

Comment: I tried with both String -
jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.123.99:1521:HERMES and
jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.123.99:1521/HERMES

but got same error. :(